# How to export an HTML table into MongoDB

Tags: node.js, html, express, mongoose

I am stuck at exporting an HTML table into mongodb in a node.js environnement.
Each document in my collection is a student with different infos such as name, class he is attending, marks in different subjects.

Each row in my HTML table is a student with name, subject and many marks. Mark's value are editable so that user can change them.

I would like to update the modified data in the table into my DB collection, but I just dunno how to do so.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any kind of frontend frameworks? It's kind of difficult to answer your question without details.

Comment: Well, im just starting with all this to be honnest. So im not using any, just coding with node and express to see where i can go. My table is populated from the DB and some ejs code. In the other hand, id like to update changes made to that table into my DB. If there is one student, i know how to do it via some proper route in express, but i just cant figure out how to do it with mutliple changes for multiple students because that implies multiple _id in my DB to be updated. Hope im clear enough to get some help.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap a form around it and process it through a POST.

Comment: I thought I would do that. I just dont know how to exactly. Say table has just 2 rows. First row is related to student with _id=1 with marks M1=14, M2=18 and M3=7 and second row is related to student with _id=45 with marks M1=0 M2=15 and M3=7.How do I route all this through just one route ?

Comment: Well you will have to play around with e.g. jQuery-Selectors. If each row has ID=1 you can select every value of the row which contains ID=1.

Comment: My problem is not to find id's. Each row is made this way : first two <td> are first name and name (not editable). The next three <td> are editable text containing a mark. There are several rows (one per student). The user can change whichever marks he wants to. I still cant figure out how to POST this, because i've got multiple id's to handle. Is the following possible : student/id1?m1=value&m1=value&m3=value?id2&m1=value&m2=value&m3=value